# Not able to create database due to no privileges in PHPMyadmin 

Tags: mysql

I cant create mysql databases in phpmyadmi. It says that i don't have privileges. how do i create databases now

Comment: Why use phpadmin in a world where MySQL Workbench exists, and has even been built to work with the free os varieties if so required.

Comment: Download here in case you decide to use a true GUI MySQL system instead of a single directional web based --> https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

PHPMyadmin is mysql tool where you are not given permissions to create databases

A way is to login at cpanel and then click at Site Management Tools / MySQL Databases
And in MySQL Databases You can make Mysql database and permission (username And Password)
for make one database with permission you must :
Make a mysql database
make a Username and password
join database with username and password permission

Comment: Your answer is inaccurate! PHPMYadmin allow create database.

Comment: enlighten me how if their are no privileges , how can u do that

Comment: @umar You know the root problem is lied on the privileges not about phpmyadmin. Would not that contradict with your statement? **PHPMyadmin is mysql tool SO you can't create databases**